# Profile picture is not showing up properly

Tags: bug, profile-picture

Until now I was uploading random images for my display picture on Stack Overflow. Today I uploaded my photo on Stack Overflow. It was uploaded successfully but the top most bar of the website is showing me the image like below. I suspected it is bug or something is wrong with the image uploaded by me. I reloaded the page number of times but all in vain:

[image]

On **Re-uploading**

[image]

Thanks to all!

Comment: Clear your cache? Try a different browser? The thumbnail on your post looks fine.

Comment: You need to flag more things.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Reproduced for your 24x24 thumbnail image:

[image: broken thumbnail]

The rest of the image sizes usually used by Stack Overflow are fine:

[image: thumbnail]
  [image: thumbnail]
  [image: thumbnail]
  [image: thumbnail]

This is a [known Imgur bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166575/why-is-there-a-peeking-duck-in-my-profile-pic) where the rescale for one of the sizes failed. Just reupload your avatar to clear it.

Comment: so what now? I have to live with it. :P..  **:D** ... Because the link you referred to is almost a year ago, and the issue still persists

Comment: @nobalG: re-upload your image; I stated so in my answer. :-) I also pinged the developer on that issue.

Comment: re-uploading have done something else(see the edit),this seems to me  really a hell of an issue

Comment: @nobalG: oh boy, looks like Imgur really doesn't like that image..

Comment: Haha,Anyway i will keep re-uploading it... **:D**

Comment: @nobalG: the [original image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KGGom.jpg) can still be reuploaded..

Comment: @nobalG: on the bright side: the [24x24 thumbnail of that image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LpLR9.jpg?s=24&g=1) is fine now! :-P

Comment: Anyway I want to thank you for staring and testing my boring profile picture for so long... I will try some other pose next time so that there will be no bugs.. :p