# My profile picture isn’t showing when I open my profile

Tags: bug, profile-page, profile-picture, imgur

When I go to my user page it's not showing the image, but the small profile picture when I'm on the main page is showing.

Here's the image that's not loading:

[image: mostly a grey box]

Image Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzeB8.jpg?s=256&g=1

Comment: I've been having issues with Stack's imgur for the last ~2 days, slow pfp loads, not able to view images on the site itself but them embedding alright. It's been intermittent, but I've had issues with it.

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine I can understand that, but my profile pic isnt loading at all, no matter how long I wait or how many times I refresh, I thought it was website being slow but now I dont think so

Comment: Can see that, it appears to have all the small sizes, but is missing the source of the 128x128 size used on profile pages ([`s=256`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzeB8.jpg?s=256&g=1)).

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzeB8.jpg?s=256&g=1 seems to be unavailable. https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzeB8.jpg is an odd resolution...

Comment: @SurajRao Issue with compression?

Comment: @SurajRao https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzeB8.jpg?s=48&g=1 The s=48 one thats shows on the header is ok...?

Comment: Possible dupe: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275987/profile-picture-is-not-showing-up-properly?rq=1

Comment: Hum, I also noticed some "strange" Behaviour related to 'Profile Picture' (not loading, the SO Pages would never completely load), both for myself and for "some" User Pages, but that was about 2 weeks/10 days ago, for a few days... I thought it was related to "Lazy Loading" + I use a Combo of 'uBlock' + 'Userscripts' Scripts controlling the SO Inbox-Bar + I block 'Gravatar', so I didn't really bother investigating anything as I thought it was related to my Config... And it all worked again correctly after a few days, while I didn't change/update anything... (FF100 'Portable' on Win10_Pro.)